# Absolute images with https URL are not working in itextsharp.xmlworker

Tags: .net

Absolute images with https URL are not working in itextsharp.xmlworker. Same images are working with http perfectly. Please note that I can view the images by typing https url and they also working fine on the website. Any help would be welcome.

Comment: This post needs more detailed information. See [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was related to not having https access on the server itself. The issue was resolved when the website domain name added in the server host file.